# InputSystem subscribe function doesn't work anymore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm using the unity input system and trying to make my inventory script. I'm trying to use my function on 'performed' state but when I make my 'OpenInventory()' it gives me this error:"Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Action<UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext>'". I don't know why is this happening because I've been working like this and it was working just fine (I'm fairly new to unity). I don't know if this would help but I've just moved from Windows 10 to 11. Thank you in advance
[image]

[image]

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Method parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods#method-parameters-vs-arguments).

Answer (score 1):

When You adding handler to Your performed event, try to remove parantheses after reference:
"... += OpenInventory();" change to "... += OpenInventory;"
I think, this should fix an issue.

Comment: Tysm this fixed it. How can i be so blind :)